# Apache httpd24 with mod24_ssl is not redirecting from http to https

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I have my Amazon linux server and I had been installed httpd24 and mod24_ssl.
I had been setup ssl certificate in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file with https redirect instructions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com:80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName example.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

But the `httpd` starts normally without any issue. But the redirection is not working. I have other file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`here. What I might have missed.? I come across many articles but those didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `RewriteEngine on`Please add that to the config file and restart Apache. Check edited below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com:80
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName example.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes. Silly mistake by me. Thanks much. I did changed but now its giving too many redirects while loading the page.